# IKev2 VPN Event ID 20209 - Server Authentication

Tags: vpn, certificate, windows-server-2019, ikev2

I have made only one certificate for VPN access with ikev2. Within 2 days i got event id 20209, even though I didn't tried to connect. The certificate is still with me and no one else has access to it. But event viewer states that

```
A connection between the VPN server and the VPN client 92.63.194.91 has been established, but the VPN connection cannot be completed. The most common cause for this is that a firewall or router between the VPN server and the VPN client is not configured to allow Generic Routing Encapsulation (GRE) packets (protocol 47).
```

This IP has been flagged for VPN BruteForce attempts at many sites.
I just want to know how did the manage to connect without certificate?

Answer (score 0):

The list of [RRAS event IDs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/824866/list-of-event-ids-for-the-routing-and-remote-access-service) ends on 20208, but according to [Netsurion EventTracker](http://kb.eventtracker.com/evtpass/evtPages/EventId_20209_RemoteAccess_65499.asp), 20209:

> This event is logged when a connection between the VPN server and the
>   VPN client has been established but the VPN connection cannot be
>   completed.

This is not an event of a successful VPN connection, but a failed connection attempt. It could be the lack of the correct client certificate or a different connection type altogether. This is not something you should worry about. Notice that *a connection* must be established to negotiate the VPN tunnel even if it fails: it doesn't refer to a successful VPN connection.